# How to remove special characters and multiple spaces from a string

Tags: ruby

I want to remove all special characters (including spaces) from a string's beginning and end and replace consecutive spaces with one. For example,

```
"      !:;:§"   this string is normal.   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"     "
```

should become:

```
"this string is normal"
```

I want to allow `!` and `?` at the end of the string.

```
"      !:;:§"   this  string is normal?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      "
"      !:;:§"   this string    is very normal!   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      "
"      !:;:§"   this string is     very normal!?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      "
```

should become:

```
"this string is normal?"
"this string is normal!"
"this string is normal!?"
```

This is all for getting nice titles in an app.

Can someone help me please? Or does anyone know a good regex command for nice titles?

Comment: Show us what have you tried.

Comment: nothing :( It's 8 am, Ive allready worked through the night and I dont know how to do a regex for this. I would start maybe to find the first ascii character and cut the string till the last one but how to detect multiple spaces in between I dont know

Comment: Define "special characters".

Comment: so it should remove the word "very"?

Comment: _"It's 8 am, Ive allready worked through the night"_ – better get some sleep.

Answer (score 2):

Do it step by step:

```
str.
  gsub(/\A\W+/, ''). # remove garbage from the very beginning
  gsub(/\W*\z/) { |m| m[/\A\p{Punct}*/] }. # leave trailing punctuation
  gsub(/\s{2,}/, ' ') # squeeze
```

Comment: Why are you not using `squeeze`?

Comment: Why are you passing a block via proc?

Comment: 1. For the sake of being regex-agnostic as requested. 2. For no reason, updated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
R = /
    (?:           # begin a non-capture group
      \p{Alnum}+  # match one or more alphanumeric characters
      [ ]+        # match one or more spaces
    )*            # end non-capture group and execute zero or more times
    \p{Alnum}+    # match one or more alphanumeric characters
    [!?]*         # match zero or more characters '!' and '?'
    /x            # free-spacing regex definition mode

def extract(str)
  str[R].squeeze(' ')
end

arr = [
  '      !:;:§"   this  string is normal?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      ',
  '      !:;:§"   this string    is very normal!   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      ',
  '      !:;:§"   this string is     very normal!?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      ',
  '      !:;:§"   cette  chaîne  est normale?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"    '
]
arr.each { |s| puts extract(s) }
```

prints

```
this string is normal?
this string is very normal!
this string is very normal!?
cette chaîne est normale?
```

See the doc for `\p{Alnum}` in [Regexp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Regexp.html) (search for "\p{} construct").

I wrote the regular expression in free-spacing mode in order to document each step. It would conventionally be written as follows.

```
/(?:\p{Alnum}+ +)*\p{Alnum}+[!?]*/
```

Notice that in free-spacing mode I put a space in a character class. Had I not done so the space would have been removed before the regular expression was evaluated.

If non-alphanumeric characters, other than spaces, are permitted in the interior of the string, change the regular expression to the following.

```
def extract(str)
  str.gsub(R,'')
end

R = /
    \A              # match the beginning of the string
    [^\p{Alnum}]+   # match one non-alphanumeric characters
    |               # or
    [^\p{Alnum}!?]  # match a character other than a alphanumeric, '!' and '?'
    [^\p{Alnum}]+   # match one non-alphanumeric characters
    \z              # match the end of the string
    |               # or
    [ ]             # match a space...
    (?=[ ])         # ...followed by a space
    /x              # free-spacing regex definition mode

extract '  !:;:§"   this  string $$ is abnormal?   "§$"  $"$§"  '
```

prints

```
"this string $$ is abnormal?"
```

Answer (score 1):

This will regex will:

1. Question and exclamantion marks that are not preceded by a "normal" character or a question or exclamation mark.
2. Whitespaces that are not preceded by a "normal" character
3. All non-"normal" characters
4. The word "very"

(I assume "normal" characters in this case are `0..9`, `a..z` and `A..Z`).

```
str = '"      !:;:§"   this string is     very normal!?   "§$"§"$"§$    $"$§"      "'

str.gsub(/
  (?:\bvery\s+) |
  (?:(?<![A-Za-z\d!?])[!?]) |
  (?:(?<![A-Za-z\d])\s) |
  [^A-Za-z\s\d!?]
/x, '')

=> "this string is normal!?"
```